# Did my front brake rotors need to be replaced?

Tags: brakes

I have a 2006 Chevy Aveo HB,only 44K miles in mint cond. Mechanically and body, etc... I just had a lot of 'maintenance work' done on it, I'm keeping it till I or it dies. After taking it home, I heard a LOUD noise from the front, like going over the middle of a bridge or the front bearings about to blow up! I just had all that front end work done,and here is this LOUD noise. So I go back and found out that 'your brake pads are WAY to big for the car, they belong on a truck!, they are dragging on your rotors!,thats the noise, and you need new rotors/pads'.That means it was two years of dragging on the rotors! They were still thick as new,but looked glazed and bluish to me. They said since they were warped they needed to be replaced,and put the right size pads  on. Was this a story to get the $300 bill I paid? Or true? Don't rotors get turned anymore? I mean 44K miles, ALL city driving. But still, only the second set to pads,and yet new rotors?  Did I get taken??

Comment: Can’t say wherher you got taken or not without further info... did you measure the rotors for thickness and runout? Were the pistons checked for free movement in the calipers, were the calipers checked? Cars with such low mileage can easily suffer binding issues in calipers and pistons...

Comment: Does the car have a vibration or wobble under braking?